# Where is threshold for cluster strategy in openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

In openlayers 2.8 there was a threshold associated with the cluster strategy as per ticket https://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/1815.

In openlayers 3 there is no mention of it anywhere (and the strategy paradigm seems to be gone as well).
http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster.html

Does anyone know if there exist a ticket for this feature?

Comment: This is not supported in ol3. Feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues) or even better open a [pull request](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paradigm has changed considerably.  In OpenLayers 3 you create a new layer, with a cluster style, and the "threshold" is set as a maxResolution, or minResolution in the layer's options.
Similar to:

```
var clusterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                visible: true,
                zIndex: insightMap.totalServcies - element.SortOrder,
                id: Id,                                           
                serviceId: element.Id,
                minResolution: clusteringThreshold,
                cluster: true,
            });
```

You can also use minZoom and maxZoom according to the documentaiton, but I've encountered issues with them performing consistently.

Comment: Do you have an example of this working ? I am unsure I understand how this can be used as a clustering threshold.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

It's actually possible to have a **proper cluster threshold** without recompiling the library. You need to use the geometry of each feature (from the `features` property of the cluster) in the style function.

```js
const noClusterStyles = [];
vectorLayer.setStyle(feature => {
  const features = feature.get('features');
  if (features.length > 5) {
    return clusterStyle;
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; ii = features.length; i < ii; ++i) {
      const clone = noClusterStyles[i] ? noClusterStyles[i] : noClusterStyle.clone();
      clone.setGeometry(features[i].getGeometry());
      noClusterStyles[i] = clone;
    }
    noClusterStyles.length = features.length;
    return noClusterStyles;
  }
});
```

Thank you to [@ahocevar](https://github.com/ahocevar) for the [code snippet](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8389#issuecomment-407756981).

Another solution would require modifying the OL3 library itself.

The ol.source.Cluster.prototype.cluster_ function has the following code snippet :

```js
var neighbors = this.source_.getFeaturesInExtent(extent);
ol.DEBUG && console.assert(neighbors.length >= 1, 'at least one neighbor found');
neighbors = neighbors.filter(function(neighbor) {
  var uid = ol.getUid(neighbor).toString();
  if (!(uid in clustered)) {
    clustered[uid] = true;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});


// Add the following
// If one element has more too many neighbors, register it as a cluster of one 
// Size-based styling should be handled separately, in the layer style function

let THRESHOLD= 3;
if(neighbors.length > THRESHOLD) {
     this.features_.push(this.createCluster_(neighbors));
} else {
    for(var j = 0 ; j < neighbors.length ; j++) {
        this.features_.push(this.createCluster_([neighbors[j]]));
    }
}
```